# Are there any solid Line Tracing Libraries/Algorithms available?

Tags: algorithm, trace

Is there an algorithm or library that is available for free which can be used to trace a line from one end to the other given that tracing actually has to happen from a picture or a live video feed?

Take this as an example, imagine pointing your phone camera to a piece of white paper which has a black line across it. Is there an algorithm/library that will help me achieve the tracing of the black line and then maybe show it as a blue line digitally on the phone while previewing?

Is this got to do with Ray tracing by any chance?

I'd prefer a C library as it is the fastest in execution, but i'm happy with java or js also!

Answer (score 1):

[OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) contains lots of vision/recognition algorithms, is widely used, and Open Source.

It includes algorithms upto things like face recognition, so I think line tracing is well within its scope.

It is probably worth adding that to highlight a high-contrast line, there is no need to identify it as a 'line'. Instead highlight a bunch of very different pixel values using a convolution, or weighted threshold (a bit like one generation of the game of Life :-)

Comment: Sweet! Thanks :)
Quick side question, is there a javascript version available ? :) :)
(i'll accept your answer as soon as i've tested it out, or maybe if someone else who has used it agrees with you)

Comment: OpenCV seems to be a swiss army knife :) is there a smaller and simpler and maybe more specific library for this?

Comment: @Akash Ramani - Yes, I understand what you mean. There are almost certainly smaller simpler libraries, but I can't suggest one. The simple case of highlighting a high-contrast line can be done by a 2D n*n Convolution. That is relatively straightforward to write. You can find it by searching for "C 2D convolution", or JavaScript. You might find optimised versions. Once past that, if you want to turn it into a sequence of vectors and do other things, then the effort to learn OpenCV _might_ start to pay back. Sorry I cant be more help.